# connecting OpenOCD to BeagleBone, ftdi device not recognized

Tags: debugging, jtag, ftdi, openocd

I am trying to connect openOCD to BeagleBone via onboard FTDI JTAG Emulator on Windows 7 x64. I have installed the ftdi driver 64bit that came with BeagleBone. when i connect the BBone to windows, USB Serial Converter A and B shows up along with COM port.

the hardware id of device-managers shows up as:

```
USB\VID_0403&PID_6010
```

I have downloaded openOCD 0.6.1 with both 32 & 64 bit binaries and ti_beaglebone.cfg script and the VID PID matches as above.

I have tried executing:

```
openocd-x64-0.6.1.exe -f board/ti_beaglebone.cfg
```

But it doesn't recognize the FTDI at all and shows up following lines:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.6.1 (2012-10-07-10:39)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
adapter speed: 16000 kHz
trst_and_srst separate srst_gates_jtag trst_push_pull srst_open_drain
Warn : unable to open ftdi device (trying more): device not found
Error: unable to open ftdi device: device not found
in procedure 'init'
```

I have tried both 32 and 64-bit binaries of OpenOCD and no luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hey guys, are you still looking for solution on this then I have a good news. Here's a link:  to my blog explaining how to do this. I finally got it to work. http://nishanth9.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/beaglebone-and-openocd/